# What's the difference between these two version

Tags: sql, database, join, select, group-by

What is the difference between the 2 versions given below??

```
Suppliers(sid:integer, sname:string, address:string)
Parts(pid:integer, pname:string, color:string)
Catalog(sid:integer, pid:integer, cost:real)
```

Find the sids of suppliers who supply a red part or a green part:

**Version 1:**

```
SELECT S.sid    
FROM Suppliers S, Parts P, Catalog C
WHERE S.sid = C.sid AND P.pid = C.pid AND (P.color = 'red' OR P.color = 'green')
```

**Version 2:**

```
SELECT C.sid    
FROM Parts P, Catalog C
WHERE P.pid = C.pid AND (P.color = 'red' OR P.color = 'green')
```

Comment: If you need only "sid" then the second query is enough. But If you need supplier details then you need to join "Suppliers" table also. In first query, if the "sid" available in "Suppliers" table then only it will return that id otherwise that particular id will not come.

Comment: You need use `inner join` please add you **DBMS**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data from the table you select. If you want to select `sid` from Suppliers table you can use first version. Or if you want from Catalog table, you can use second version. But there is no need of using `OR` clause in your query. Instead you have to use `IN` clause. Or should be used only when you filter alternative conditions from two different columns.

```
SELECT S.sid
FROM Suppliers S, Parts P, Catalog C
WHERE S.sid = C.sid AND P.pid = C.pid AND P.color IN ('red', 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

The second query is more efficient, since it does not brings the `supplier` table (which you don't need, since you just want the supplier `sid`, which can be found in the `parts`  table).

However I don't think that it does exactly what you want. If a supplier has more than one red or green part in their catalog, it will appear several times in the result set. I would recommend aggregation instead.

```
select c.sid
from parts p
inner join catalog c on c.pid = p.pid
where p.color in ('red', 'green')
group by s.id
```

Note that this version of the query uses standard, explicit joins (with the `on` keyword) rather than implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause): this syntax from decades ago makes it much more difficult to write, read and maintain the query, and should not be used in new code.